# mySQL Indexes suggestion software

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-optimization

Is there any software that can analyze a mySQL query, and suggest a specific index creation.

I know its best to do it by hand, but i need to something that can save some time.

Many thanks,

Comment: [EXPLAIN?](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html)

Comment: I need something that writes the SQL for the creation of an index.

Answer (score 6):

The MySQL Enterprise Monitor has a [Query Analyer](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-monitor/2.3/en/mem-qanal-using.html) feature.  But MEM is not free.

**Percona Toolkit** is a free, open-source software product that gives you most of the information to do the analysis yourself.

- [`pt-query-digest --explain`](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/pt-query-digest.html) analyzes the top queries that appear in your query log and shows you their current optimization plan.
- [`pt-index-usage`](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/pt-index-usage.html) analyzes the queries in your query log and shows you how they are using indexes (and also shows you indexes that it considered but decided not to use).

Full disclosure: I work for Percona.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this won't automate the process, but it explains how you can figure out what the best INDEX is for a given SELECT:  [Index Cookbook](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

I agree with Bill that pt-query-digest (together with the slowlog) is an excellent way to identify the "worst" queries.  (Disclosure:  I do not work for Percona.)